# Jquery-ui drag and drop: using a draggable more than once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can an element be dragged and drop more than once with jquery's ui, since normally the draggable element is moved when drop is triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jquery draggable's [helper](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-helper) option `helper: 'clone'` and handle the drop event like so:

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems to work fine! By the way, how do you remove the current div in the droppable spot when you drop a new one? (At the moment, they pile on top of one another)

Comment: @adam: throw it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and i'll be happy to take a look.  not sure what you mean offhand.

Comment: @DavidWick So what do you suggest regarding that issue?

Comment: @adam: not exactly sure was happening there... [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dwick/hfWz7/11/) should work though.

Comment: Thanks for the progress!
1) Is it possible to set it in a way that when you drop a new element, it replaces the current one (if there is one) instead of piling up like the one you just did?
2) Also, is there a way to allow the current div (the appended one) to be draggable (on the fiddle you did, it is fixed)

Comment: @David Wick (to complete upper comment): (2) By allowing to drag the appended div, the user will be able to remove it by dragging it out of the droppable area (instead of clicking on "Remove" as you did)

Comment: @DavidWick what is the class assigned when you append your div?